# How to give CSS3 support to IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, css

I use [IE7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) but it doesn't have **CSS3** support. I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) always in my projects.

What is the best lightweight way to give all **CSS3** selectors and properties support to IE 6,7,8?

**I'm not asking for HTML5 support only asking to give CSS3 support in as much as light on performance way.**

Comment: Don't support IE6. It is a dying browser (Even GMail wont support it).

Comment: We take matter to support IE 6 is a matter of accessibility not compatibility. and I charge extra for IE6 compatibility. so no problem

Comment: Charge extra? What person in their right mind would pay extra for IE6 support? Talk about flushing money down the toilet.

Comment: @animuson - some corporate clients still want IE 6 compatibility.

Comment: @animuson, you obviously do not work in corporate America.  I have a friend who works at a place that is just now considering upgrading to IE 7 (don't ask)

Comment: You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear.

Comment: use http://code.google.com/intl/en/chrome/chromeframe/

Comment: @Maksim bad idea - Google Chrome Frame requires a client-side install, so your site would only benefit for those users with GCF already on their computer (much like Flash, but with a much much lower takeup)

Comment: iE7.js has been upgraded to IE9.js since this topic was posted. IE9.js supports many (but not all) CSS3 features

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try keith clarks IE CSS3 pseudo selector emulator: http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/ie-css3/

I haven't personally used it but it manually parses your css file and adapts it for ie-browsers.

A downside is you're relying on js for css functionality..

Comment: how to use this? it's confusing "To use ie-css3 on your website you'll need to download the ie-css3.js  script and one of the supported JavaScript libraries  and include them both in your pages as shown in the code sample. "

Answer (score 4):

the IE7.js project linked in the question has recently added IE9.js. This brings more CSS3 selector support to legacy IE.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem with those IE8.js to IE9.js things are they made your IE browser lag even at local site

Answer (score 3):

What your looking for is this new library: CSS3 PIE

http://css3pie.com/

It gives IE6-8 several CSS3 attribute support.

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread on this running on webmasters.stackexchange.com with a lot of projects listed:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-enable-css3-features-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/2397#2397

Answer (score 0):

You can't really change how a browser implements in rendering process or featured contained in that renderer.  IE9 is supposed to support many (all?) CSS3 features, but you will not get to use it for some time.

Like you said, you will need a third-party tool for this.

You might be able to use Google Chrome Frame, but I am not sure if that supports CSS3 yet.

Comment: IE9 definitely won't support all of CSS3 and not as many as the other browsers.

Comment: @Rob it already scores 68/100 in acid3 test. and it already supports most important part of css3 selectors. see http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive

Comment: @ Maksim Burning It's IE... Until they redevelop there entire program from scratch it will always be bad. They need to either stop saying they are there own standard or actually develop a decent piece of software.

Comment: @Maksim - "Most important part" is not "all" and scoring 68/100 is about 30 points behind where everyone else is now. In addition, their DOM and javascript support is lacking, SVG is missing properties, no support for the canvas element and on and on.

Comment: @Rob it's not a final version

Comment: @Maksim - Microsoft used that excuse for betas of IE7 and IE8, too. Maybe they'll get close to 100 in two years but they still have not stated any plans to upgrade or fix anything else I mentioned, my main point, they're running as fast as they can just to stay in one place, and that is years behind all the other browsers.

Comment: @ROB ie8 scores 20/100. ie9 preview 1 scores 55/100. ie9 preview 2 scores 68/100. and they promised to raise this score by final release. and i like this.

Comment: @Maksim - Acid3 is nice, maybe important, but only a small part of what makes a browser good. IE9 will NOT be good for the reasons I stated above and for those failures will pale in comparison to every other browser.

Comment: @Dustin, Chrome Frame is the same rendering engine as Chrome, so they have the most CSS3 support of any browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Chrome Frame http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/
This will make your IE render and work as Chrome, which supports all CSS3. All you have to do is to add this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">`
 after your `<head>`. You can try it out online at http://www.typefolly.com/
You have several CSS3 options there like text-shadow or transform.

Comment: You also have to persuade every single IE user who visits your site to install it.

Comment: Indeed but if Google is giving support for this it is very probable that the Chrome Frame to be cached.

Comment: Err. It's a browser plugin, not a piece of JS. I said users have to **install** it, not let their browser download it invisibly in the background at a small cost of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a good workaround to use ccs3 properties in i-e 6 to 9

http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/